# Skip a view and load the view before it

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have three views (**View1**, **View2** and **View3**). When i swipe right, i need to skip '**View2**' and load the '**View1**'.i am using a navigation controller. how to pop both **View1** and **View2** from navigation controller and **load** the '**View1**'. I used two popViewController , but it didn't worked as i expected.

Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

```
[navController popToViewController:viewController1 animated:YES];
```

Comment: I am getting a warning: Semantic Issue: Method '-popToViewController:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: I received SIGABRT error. When i run the project with the code: **[self.navigationController popToViewController:view1 animated:YES]**